# How to use Python to open Kmz file and display it on interactive map?

Tags: python

I'm using python 3.11.3 on windows 10, and need to open Kmz file and display it on an interactive map.
Anyone has experience on that matter to guide me how to write a code to do this function

I tried below example but seems that it's not working with python 3.11.3

```
`import folium
import zipfile
import io

# Load the KMZ file and extract the KML data
with zipfile.ZipFile('path to file.kmz', 'r') as kmz_file:
kml_file = kmz_file.read('doc.kml')

# Load the KML data into a Folium map
map = folium.Map(location=[0, 0], zoom_start=2)
folium.Kml(io.BytesIO(kml_file)).add_to(map)

# Display the map
map.save('map.html')`
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, I have used Australia.kmz file downloaded from [datapages website](https://www.datapages.com/gis-map-publishing-program/gis-open-files/global-framework/global-heat-flow-database/kmz-files-list).

I have used [fastkml](https://fastkml.readthedocs.io/) library to translate KML string content to KML object:

```
import folium
import zipfile
import io

from fastkml import kml

# read KML content 
kmz = zipfile.ZipFile("Australia_KMZ/Australia.kmz", 'r')  # extract zip file first, then read kmz file inside the extracted folder
kml_content = kmz.open('doc.kml', 'r').read()  # kml content

# create KML object
k = kml.KML()
k.from_string(kml_content)

# read features from docs to folders to records and then extract geometries - in my case, Shapely points
docs = list(k.features())
folders = []
for d in docs:
    folders.extend(list(d.features()))
records = []
for f in folders:
    records.extend(list(f.features()))
geoms = [element.geometry for element in records]  # extract geometry

# plot the geoms - latitude (y), longitude (x)
import folium
mapit = folium.Map()
for geom in geoms:
    folium.Marker(location=(geom.y, geom.x), fill_color='#43d9de', radius=2).add_to(mapit)
mapit.save('map.html')
```

Comment: thank you @Ehsan , It gives an error "AttributeError: 'Folder' object has no attribute 'geometry'" for code line :geoms = [element.geometry for element in records]  # extract geometry

Comment: Did you try it with your own data or Australia dataset? because the Australia dataset works for me. In case it is your data, maybe better to share it or you can debug and see the structure of your own file. Happy to help in case you can share your data or a sample of it.